# ios 14, webp animation flahes with a white background in safari and chrome

Tags: ios, animation, safari, ios14, webp

`.webp` flashes with a white background like below link in iOS 14 safari, chrome.

https://tcoz5.codesandbox.io/
[code](https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-wood-tcoz5?file=/src/App.tsx)

in desktop PC Chrome, Animation works naturally.

in iOS 14 Safari or chrome, Animation works unnaturally.

Please how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this problem myself; it seems that animated WebP with transparency have rendering problems in Safari.

The only solution I could find so far is using APNG for all versions of Safari and using WebP for Firefox/Chromium.

I created a [Webkit bug report](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=217897) referencing back to this question

Comment: in August 2021, it still presents.

Answer (score 0):

Recently i did website that is doing something like picture slide of radar images and i used `<picture>` with `<img>` .png fallback with subtle animation that does fade out.

Whatever i did pictures will blink on ipad or iphone with ios 14 but not load fallback img and on PC and Adnroid everything was ok!

I was sure that my iphone cannot load images fast enough but lastly like a last hope i disabled the animation.
And that was the problem!!! Ios 14 just **does not like** animation with **webp**.